# Movement Not Being Stopped

Tags: javascript, html, css, collision, pacman

I am trying to prevent a character from crossing objects w/ a blue border. I have included some debugging comments so I can track how the code is being executed, and it seems to be fine logically. However, they way I am trying to prevent movement is not working. And I'm wondering why. Here is my code:

//My HTML Code

```
<div id="title">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PM-style.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="Pac-Man.js">
    </script>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Pac-Man.js">
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Grid.js">
    </script>


    <title> Pac-Man Game </title>

</div>
```

```
<body>

    <div class="mazeboard">

        <hl> WELCOME!!!</hl>


    </div>





    <p id="buttons">

        <script src="Pac-Man.js">
        </script>

        <button onclick="myMove()" id="beginButton"> Begin Game </button>

        <button onclick="increment()" id="pause"> &nbsp  Pause &nbsp  </button>

        <button onclick="reset()" id="reset"> &nbsp  Start Over &nbsp  </button>


        <button onclick="nextStage1()"> &nbsp  Next &nbsp  </button>


    </p>


    <div class='status-window'>
        <h2> SCORE: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <span> TIME: </span> <span id="output">  </span> </h2>


        <script>
        </script>

    </div>


    </div>

    <div class="realm">




        <canvas width="800" height="450" style="border: 2px solid blue; background-color: black; border-radius: 20px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; align-content: center;" id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
        <!--  Comment  This is where the walls go! -->
        <div id='game-window'>
            <div id="outerwall" class="game-window" data-index="1"> </div>
            <div id="left-wall" class="game-window" data-index="2"></div>
            <div id="left-wallTop" class="game-window" data-index="3"></div>
            <div id="left-wallMiddle" class="game-window" data-index="4"></div>
            <div id="left-wallBottom1" class="game-window" data-index="5"></div>
            <div id="left-wallBottom2" class="game-window" data-index="6"></div>
            <div id="top-wall" class="game-window" data-index="7"></div>

            <div id="middle-wall1" class="game-window" data-index="8"></div>
            <div id="middle-wall2" class="game-window" data-index="9"></div>
            <div id="right-wall" class="game-window" data-index="10"></div>
            <div id="center-block" class="game-window" data-index="11"> </div>
            <div id="bottom-block1" class="game-window" data-index="12"></div>
            <div id="bottom-block2" class="game-window" data-index="13"></div>
            <div id="bottom-block3" class="game-window" data-index="14"></div>
            <div id="bottom-block4" class="game-window" data-index="15"></div>
            <div id="right-bottom1" class="game-window" data-index="16"></div>
            <div id="right-bottom2" class="game-window" data-index="17"></div>
            <div id="right-bottom" class="game-window" data-index="18"></div>
            <div id="center2" class="game-window" data-index="19"></div>
            <div id="opencenter" class="game-window" data-index="20"></div>
            <div id="center3" class="game-window" data-index="21"></div>
            <div id="hole1" class="game-window" data-index="22"></div>
            <div id="hole2" class="game-window" data-index="23"></div>
            <div id="hole3" class="game-window" data-index="24"></div>
            <div id="hole4" class="game-window" data-index="25"></div>
            <div></div>

        </div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="Pac-man.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Ghost.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Grid.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Game.js"></script>

        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
            }
        </script>

        <div id='pacman' class='realm'> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/14/17/12/pacman-34643_960_720.png" id="pacman"> </div>

        <div id='ghost' class='realm'> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/12/31/pacman-145852_960_720.png" id="ghost"> </div>



    </div>




     </body>


     <footer>

    </footer>

     </html>
```

//Moving the Pacman Character (JAVASCRIPT)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('jQuery has loaded!');
console.log("Ready!");



$pacman = $(document.getElementById('pacman'));
pacman = $pacman;

STEP_SIZE = 15;


var keys = {};



document.getElementById("beginButton").onclick = function() {
    gameStart()
};



function gameStart() {
    start();


    pacManPositions = {
        'left': parseInt(pacman.css('left')),
        'right': parseInt(pacman.css('left')) + pacman.width(),
        'top': parseInt(pacman.css('top')),
        'bottom': parseInt(pacman.css('top')) + pacman.height()
    };

   //Setting up conditions to determine movement or not
    collision2 = false;
    collisions = true;

    function collision() {


        $(".game-window").each(function() {


            var walls = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            walls = $(this);



            for (var i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {


                var name = walls[i].getAttribute('id');
                var border = $(this).css('border-color');

                var position = $(this).position();

                if (border == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {


                    wallPositions = {
                        'left': position.left,
                        'right': position.left + $(this).width(),
                        'top': position.top,
                        'bottom': position.top + pacman.height()
                    };




                    pacManPositions = {
                        'left': parseInt(pacman.css('left')),
                        'right': parseInt(pacman.css('left')) +
                            pacman.width(),
                        'top': parseInt(pacman.css('top')),
                        'bottom': parseInt(pacman.css('top')) +
                            pacman.height()
                    };


                    if ((pacManPositions.left <= wallPositions.left && pacManPositions.right >= wallPositions.left) ||
                        (pacManPositions.left <= wallPositions.right && pacManPositions.right >= wallPositions.right) ||
                        (pacManPositions.left <= wallPositions.right && pacManPositions.right >= wallPositions.left)) {



                        if ((pacManPositions.top >= wallPositions.top && pacManPositions.top <= wallPositions.bottom) ||
                            (pacManPositions.top <= wallPositions.top && pacManPositions.top >= wallPositions.bottom - 33) ||
                            (pacManPositions.top >= wallPositions.top && pacManPositions.bottom <= wallPositions.bottom)) {
                            collisions = false;

                            return true;

                            collision2 = true;

                        }

                    }


                }
            }


        });

    }


    //Moving Pac Man w/ Keys

    $(document).on('keydown', movePacman);


    function movePacman(event) {


        console.log(event.which);

        switch (event.which) {
            //moving right
            case 39:
                console.log('right');

                // pacman.css("left", (pacman.position().left + 10) + "px");
                // var leftVal = pacman.css("left", (pacman.position().left + 10) + "px");   
                var leftVal = parseInt(pacman.css('left')) + STEP_SIZE;


                if (leftVal > ($('#outerwall').width() - pacman.width())) {
                    leftVal = ($('#outerwall').width() - pacman.width()) - 0;
                }


                collision();

                if (collision() == true) {
                    var leftVal = 0;
                    $('#pacman').css('left', leftVal);

                } else {

                    $('#pacman').css('left', leftVal);

                    break;

                }



               break;
                //moving down
            case 40:
                console.log('down');
                var downVal = parseInt(pacman.css('top')) + STEP_SIZE;



                if (downVal > ($('#outerwall').height() + pacman.height()) - 70) {
                    downVal = ($('#outerwall').height()) - pacman.height() + 1;
                }

                collision();

                if (collision() == true) {


                } else {

                    $('#pacman').css('top', downVal);

                    break;

                }



                break;
                //moving left
            case 37:
                console.log('left');

                var leftVal = parseInt(pacman.css('left')) - STEP_SIZE;

                if (leftVal < 0) {
                    leftVal = ($('#outerwall').width()) - 780;
                    //parseInt(pacman.css('left'));
                }
                collision();


                if (collision() == true) {

                } else {

                    $('#pacman').css('left', leftVal);

                    break;

                }




                // break; 

                //moving up
            case 38:
                console.log('up');
                var topVal = parseInt(pacman.css('top')) - STEP_SIZE;

                if (topVal < 0) {
                    topVal = ($('#outerwall').height()) - 430;
                }

                collision();


                if (collision() == true) {

                } else {

                    $('#pacman').css('top', topVal);

                    break;

                }

                break;

                //  break;



                //breaking
            case 32:
                console.log('break');

                break;
        }
    }


}
```

})

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the problem in the smallest amount of code to make debugging for us (and you!) easier?

Comment: @Scott How do you mean? Just wondering so I can make the modifcations

Comment: Marie, see how to create a [mcve]. We need a minimal, verifiable example of what you have now that illustrates the problem, not just a bunch of JS out of context.

Comment: @Scott  I have added context (html) and simplied my javascript w/o extraneous info, only the code needed for Pac-Man's movements

Comment: @Michael Coker I have edited and added more context (html)